# How to use gradle and IntelliJ to build a scala project?

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea

Is there a step by step tutorial on how to use gradle to build a scala project in IntelliJ? I tried to research online but couldn't find a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

The default build tool for scala is SBT. This is available in intellij. I highly recommend using it. These are the gradle docs for scala: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

```
myproject> gradle wrapper --gradle-version 5.0
myproject> ./gradlew init --type scala-library
```

Init plugin supports type='scala-library' gradle 5.0+. Notice that the second step uses gradle wrapper to initialize the scala project. This is ensure that gradle v5.0 is used irrepective of the version of gradle installed in the respective machine.